# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views - Android

Tags: java, android, multipartentity

I'm using MultipartEntityBuilder to send images to php server, I take pics and videos to device camera to a directory, and I need to save files on new ArrayList and send it to php server.

Always it's reports an error:

[image: error]

**my code**

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>
    {
        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground (String... params)
        {
            String datos = value.getText().toString();

            HttpClient httpClient = getNewHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://myurl.com");

            try
            {

path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/mydirectory";

                File fileArray = new File(path);
                ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(fileArray.listFiles()));

                int itemCount = files.size();

                MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

                builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
                {
                    builder.addPart("images[]", new FileBody(new File(path + "/" + num_img)));
                    num_img++;
                }

                builder.addTextBody("response", "prueba");

                HttpEntity entity = builder.build();

                httppost.setEntity(entity);

    //...............................

}
```

**UPDATE**

```
protected void onPostExecute (Double result)
        {
            path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/myDirectory";


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    File fileArray = new File(path);
                    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(fileArray.listFiles()));

                    int itemCount = files.size();
                    tv_files.setText("valor:" + itemCount);

                    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

                    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                    builder.addTextBody("response", "prueba");

                    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
                    {
                        builder.addPart("images[]", new FileBody(new File(path + "/" + num_img)));
                        num_img++;
                    }

                    HttpEntity entity = builder.build();

                }
            });
```

Comment: doing ui operation (accessing views) in a background thread. also pass this `value.getText().toString();` as a param to asynctask

Comment: `runOnUiThread()` @Raghunandan?

Comment: i would do the operations related to ui in `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute`.

Comment: yes, runOnUiThread() will do

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll try and I will write

Comment: okay, I write all `MultipartEntityBuilder` on `runOnUiThread()` on `onPostExecute`, but something I do bad because array its always empty, (question updated)

Comment: This is not related to your first issue my friend, start a new question. And you are not getting the picture here. You should just update the UI in a runnable an pass it to runOnUiThread() not your heavy weight task

Comment: okay, you have the reason. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is trying to say to you never touch the UI views outside any thread does not run on the `UIThread`.

In your `DoInBackground` you are trying to get the value of the `EditText`, and this is considering a touch for the UI views within a Thread does runs in the background.

**SOLUTION:**
Move the following line

```
String datos = value.getText().toString();
```

Outside `doInBackground` method to `onPreExcute()` or on the constructor of the `AsyncTask`. Just declare `String datos` as a global variable in the AsyncTask and use it in your `doInBackground()` as you want

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       datos = value.getText().toString();
    }
```